# Play Framework: how to submit a form from a modal window using a POST route

Tags: javascript, playframework, routes

I have a Play Framework app that I would like to have the function of clicking a button from the form that will open a modal window.  Once the modal window opens, the user selects a value and clicks a button which would close the modal and call the `POST` route (submit the form) to save the form.

For example, if I use the following route:

```
GET /openrecord controllers.MyController.openRecord(key: String)
```

To open the form, then I would like to call this one below from the modal when I close that modal:

```
POST /openrecord controllers.MyController.saveRecord(key: String)
```

I have tried using JavaScript to change the URL, but it just uses the `GET` route, not the `POST` route:

HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
<div><a href="javascript:wkflwApproveDeny('approve', document.getElementById('casekey').value);" class="buttonModalView" style="color: #FFFFFF;">Approve</a></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function wkflwApproveDeny(action, recordKey) {
    // Set the action field...
    var e = document.getElementById("workflowAction");
    e.value = action;
    // Now, process the record...
    window.location.href = "/openRecord/" + recordKey;  
}
```

How would I accomplish this?  Is there a standard to use to get this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need create a form for submit post.

```
function send_post(recordKey) {
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute("method", "post");
    form.setAttribute("action", "http://url/openRecord/" + recordKey);
    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
}
```

But you should rather use a JavaScript framework such as [jQuery](https://github.com/jquery/jquery)...